# Compositum of two fixed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension and suppose $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 \in \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. Next, define $F_i = L^{\langle \sigma_i \rangle}$ for $i=1,2$.

**Question**: Is there a way to describe the compositum $F_1 F_2$ as a fixed field over $L$? (i.e. is there a general description for a subgroup $H \subseteq \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ such that $F_1 F_2 = L^{H}$).

I know this is quite a general question, and it may depend very much on $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ or the elements $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$. However, if there is such a description, I would be grateful if you could point me to the right direction or give me a reference.

Comment: Since $F_1F_2$ is the *smallest* field **containing** $F_1$ and $F_2$, it corresponds to the *largest* subgroup **contained** in $\langle\sigma_1\rangle$ and $\langle\sigma_2\rangle$, by the Galois correspondence. That is, the subgroup $H$ you want is just $H=\langle\sigma_1\rangle\cap\langle\sigma_2\rangle$.